# HTML form in PHP while loop

Tags: php, html, forms, loops, while-loop

How can I put an html form into a PHP while loop?

It thought something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
<?php

$i=1;
while ($i<=5){

<form name="X" action="thispage.php" method="POST">
     <input type="text">
     <input type="submit">
</form>;

$i=$i+1;

              }

?>
```

Comment: What "doesn't work"? What's the result and what do you expect?

Answer (score 5):

You can, you just can't have raw HTML in the middle of the PHP like that. End the PHP statement before the HTML then reopen it after like this:

```
 <?php

$i=1;
while ($i<=5){
?>

<form name="X" action="thispage.php" method="POST">
     <input type="text" name="trekking">
 <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php 
   $i=$i+1;
     }

?>
```

Comment: Minor typo-problem. The `$i` increment is outside of the php tags. :)

Comment: Thanks everybody. Rick Calder's code works best. Had no idea that PHP could be interrupted with html, and then continue on as if nothing had happened.

Comment: However, this code prints the form 5 times rightaway, whereas it should really wait for the submit button to be pressed to print the next form. How can that be solved?

Comment: You didn't say that... That is a case for jQuery to replicate the form.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php

$i=1;
while ($i<=5):?>

<form name="X" action="thispage.php" method="POST">
         <input type="text" name="trekking">
     <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php $i=$i+1;

   endwhile;

?>
```

Use `endwhile` to make a nice readable separation of php and html.
Don't echo blocks of code if you don't have to.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `echo`:

```
<?php

$i=1;
while ($i<=5){

    echo '
        <form name="X" action="thispage.php" method="POST">
             <input type="text" name="trekking">
             <input type="submit">
        </form>;
    ';

    $i=$i+1;
}
?>
```

Or otherwise, open and close PHP tags:

```
<?php

$i=1;
while ($i<=5){

//closing PHP
?>

        <form name="X" action="thispage.php" method="POST">
             <input type="text" name="trekking">
             <input type="submit">
        </form>;

<?php 
//opening PHP 

    $i=$i+1;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by closing your PHP block before the HTML with `?>`, and then reopening with `<?php` before the rest of your code.

Personally though, I prefer to `echo` HTML when within PHP.  It makes your code more readable.  Also, I suggest using a `for` loop rather than what you have there.

```
<?php
for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) {
    echo '<form name="x" action="thispage.php" method="POST">',
         '<input type="text" name="trekking">',
         '<input type="submit"',
         '</form>';
}
?>
```

Comment: I have a tendency to flip back and forth between opening and closing and echoing, the problem I have with echoing is not being able to use things like Notepad++'s open/close tag finding functions.

Comment: @RickCalder, It is a matter of preference.  For me, the HTML that gets used programmatically is trivial, so I don't have a problem with this.  I also tend to do HTML first and then PHP for the dynamic parts later.  I also often use a template engine.

Comment: @Brad any recommendations on a template engine?

Comment: @Bizarre I haven't used PHP in a few years, but I used to use Smarty.  https://www.smarty.net/  It supported template inheritance, which was very handy.  You could have classes of pages, say something like home page, inner page, etc.  And then sub class them, so article might be a sub-class of inner page, and photo gallery might be a sub-class of inner page.  It's one of the best templating engine concepts I've ever seen.  Rather than simply concatenating out a header, a footer, and having opening/closing tags scattered everywhere, you end up with something much more like HTML and OOP!

Comment: @Brad, ok, thanks! I will check it out, seems like it could really accelerate the workflow for a new website design! Did you switch to nodejs stack? ruby? or stoped doing web applications? Is it worth making the switch?

Comment: @Bizarre I'm mainly working on web-based applications now rather than content-based websites.  Much of what I do is 100% client-side, so I create static sites and automate building it with webpack and various other tools.  Some of these have Node.js-based API servers which they talk to.  I've found Node excellent to work with and am happily using it for most everything these days.  Modern PHP can be solid too, it's just not something I personally have a need for at the moment.  I like the flexibility I get with Node.

Answer (score 0):

You should learn PHP first. What you trying to achieve ist pretty simple basic PHP.

But to answer your question echo `"[form-html goes here]";` inside the while loop. Make sure to escape all the other `"`.

Comment: no no no no no. You should not echo that HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is trying to output 5 forms with the same name (which I wouldn't recommend in the first place), you could try this:

```
$i=1;
$strOutput = "";
while ($i<=5){

 $strOutput .= '<form name="X" action="thispage.php" method="POST">';
     $strOutput .= '<input type="text" name="trekking">';
     $strOutput .= '<input type="submit">';
 $strOutput .= '</form>';

   $i=$i+
}

echo $strOutput;
```

*Never* use HTML inside PHP code like you did in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$i=1;
echo"<form name="X" action="thispage.php" method="POST">";
while ($i<=5)
{
    echo"<input type="text">";
    echo"<input type="submit">";
    $i++;
}
echo"</form>";

?>
```